# Why do I get error in android and fragment eventhough I add supprot-library-v4 in Intellij

Tags: android, android-fragments, intellij-idea, android-support-library

I created a basic project using Intellij 13 and android sdk 19 then I add `support-library v4.jar` to my project.

this is my main activity :

```
package com.example.testfg2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

this is "main.xml" layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MyActivity"
            />

    <fragment android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             name="com.example.testfg2.frg1"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my simple fragment class "frg1.java"

```
package com.example.testfg2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class frg1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frg_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

and here is the layout "frg_layout.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

my emulator is a 2.3.3.

when I try to run this app I will get following error :

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12:
>   Error inflating class fragment

What do I exactly missed? is there anything extra I should do to make the app working with intellij 13.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should extend `FragmentActivity`

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Base class for activities that want to use the support-based `Fragment`.